# Cannot do batch_update on Google Sheet with more than 999 rows

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

Getting the following error when trying to do a batch_update post to a google sheet. There are 5600 rows in the sheet I am trying to post to

```
('/home/xx/xxx/xx.csv', <Spreadsheet u'spreadsheet name' id:id#>, 'A5600')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xx.py", line 50, in <module>
    pasteCsv(csvFile, sheet, cell)
  File "xx.py", line 38, in pasteCsv
    return sheet.batch_update(body)
  File "/home/xx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 146, in batch_update
    'post', SPREADSHEET_BATCH_UPDATE_URL % self.id, json=body
  File "/home/xx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 73, in request
    raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {u'status': u'INVALID_ARGUMENT', u'message': u'Invalid requests[0].pasteData: GridCoordinate.rowIndex[5599] is after last row in grid[999]', u'code': 400}
```

is there a way to change the grid from [999] to a higher number so that I am able to post the csv file contents?

Comment: I thought that when you provide your current script, it will help users think of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can make a batch request to increase the number of rows in the sheet before you insert the CSV content.*

#### Example using a Batch Request:

```py
spreadsheetId = "your-spreadsheet-id"
sheetId = "sheet-id"

sh = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)

request = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "insertDimension": {
                "range": {
                  "sheetId": sheetId,
                  "dimension": "ROWS",
                  "startIndex": 999,
                  "endIndex": 5599
                },
                "inheritFromBefore": false
            }
        }
    ]
}

result = sh.batch_update(request)
```

You will need to change `sheetId` to be the gid of the sheet within the Spreadsheet you are updating.

**Remember:** rows and columns are 0-indexed, so inserting rows below row 1000 will mean having a `startIndex` of 999.

#### Example using gspread methods:

Alternatively in gspread you can directly use the `gspread.models.Worksheet.add_rows()` method:

```py
sh = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
ws = sh.get_worksheet(index)
ws.add_rows(4600)
```

#### References:

- [Row and Column Operations | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn)

  - [Insert an empty row or column](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#insert_an_empty_row_or_column)
- [API Reference - gspread 3.6.0 documentation - `add_rows(rows)`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=open_by_key#gspread.models.Worksheet.add_rows)

Comment: Getting this after adding that:

raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {u'status': u'INVALID_ARGUMENT', u'message': u"Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'insertDimension'", u'code': 400, u'details': [{u'fieldViolations': [{u'field': u'requests[0]', u'description': u"Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'insertDimension'"}], u'@type': u'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest'}]}

Comment: I updated my answer with an example using gspread methods. @MykolaZayats. Please let me know if that works.

Comment: Adding a row via gspread methods before posting fixed it. Thanks!