# Writing more than 1000 rows into Google Sheet in C#

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

This question is related to Google Sheets API (C#).

I have to write more than 1000 rows into a Google sheet, therefore I need to increase the number of rows (I got the *Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError* when I attempted to write 4640 rows).

Searching the Stack Overflow website resulted in information telling me that I needed to use *UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest* or *InsertDimensionRequest* and create a new request that could be in the same *Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate* call.

In line with this [Python example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64471596/cannot-do-batch-update-on-google-sheet-with-more-than-999-rows?rq=1), I set the properties of the *InsertDimensionRequest* instance and included them in my existing code (= publicly available C# code by Ian Preston).

The code then looks like this:

```
public void AddCells(GoogleSheetParameters googleSheetParameters, List<GoogleSheetRow> rows)
        {
            var requests = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest { Requests = new List<Request>() }; //Existing code

            int sheetId = GetSheetId(_sheetsService, _spreadsheetId, googleSheetParameters.SheetName); //Existing code

            InsertDimensionRequest insertDimensionRequest = new InsertDimensionRequest(); //Added code
            
            insertDimensionRequest.Range.SheetId = sheetId; //Added code
            insertDimensionRequest.Range.Dimension = "ROWS"; //Added code
            insertDimensionRequest.Range.StartIndex = 999; //Added code
            insertDimensionRequest.Range.EndIndex = 6999; //Added code
            insertDimensionRequest.InheritFromBefore = false; //Added code
            
            var request = new Request { UpdateCells = new UpdateCellsRequest { Start = gc, Fields = "*" } };  //Existing code
            //some code here

            var request1 = new Request { ???????? }; //code to be added - how should the request look like?

            requests.Requests.Add(request);  //Existing code
            requests.Requests.Add(request1); //Added code
         
        }
```

But I do not know how a new request can be created in C#.

My question is: How to create such an request (named as *request1* in my code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile, I have managed to figure out an answer.

```
DimensionRange dr = new DimensionRange
            {
                SheetId = sheetId,
                Dimension = "ROWS",
                StartIndex = 999,
                EndIndex = 6999 // adding extra 6000 rows
            };

var request1 = new Request { InsertDimension = new InsertDimensionRequest { Range = dr, InheritFromBefore = false } };
```

And then (the order of the requests matters):

```
requests.Requests.Add(request1);
requests.Requests.Add(request);
```

***EDIT 01-06-2022:** The entire code using the aforementioned snippet can be downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/MiroslavHustak/ElmishWPFprogressBar) - see the GoogleSheets project there.*

---

It is also possible to use `userEnteredValue`. This clears the sheet and, for me inexplicably, sets the number of rows to an unknow value, but my 4640 rows were accepted.

***EDIT 31-05-2022:** If you know more about the usage of `userEnteredValue`, feel free to elaborate on this matter.*

```
GridRange dr2 = new GridRange
            {
                SheetId = sheetId
            };

var request2 = new Request { UpdateCells = new UpdateCellsRequest { Range = dr2, Fields = "userEnteredValue" } };
```

And then (the order of the requests probably also matters):

```
requests.Requests.Add(request2);
requests.Requests.Add(request);
```